# Qt/QML:How to check for update on Android

Tags: android, qt, qml

I have searched on internet . But ı can't no answer for this topic.I have an QT/QML app for android system.I want to control program version over network then update apps according to versiyon.I have read this site :https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37221 . In this chapter ,  There is a bug.Is there a alternative way to achive this.Thank you